# Photograph of two (possibly) glam rock artists, one holding a guitar - can anyone please identify these musicians?

Tags: rock, identify-this-band

[image: Identify these musicians]

I have a box of band and concert photos from a storage locker I bought, some possibly from Woodstock. Some things that I've found in the box indicate that the owner was in the music business in some capacity.  I would really appreciate help with identifying these bands if at all possible.  This is just one of the photos and the only one of these 2.

Comment: I like this one - bring on some more :)

Comment: Just commenting to say what an awesome find that is!

Answer (score 11):

These two guys are [Marc Bolan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marc_Bolan) and [Mickey Finn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mickey_Finn_(drummer)), members of the band [T. Rex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T._Rex_(band)).

- Marc Bolan

[image: Marc Bolan]

- Mickey Finn

[image: Mickey Finn]

---

I also found a [fan work](http://www.stars-portraits.com/en/portrait-247268.html) based on this photograph, by [Paolo-Art](http://www.stars-portraits.com/en/community/Paolo-Art.html):

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Bebs has already got the ident nailed, but I thought I'd add a little more info...

The picture is post-Woodstock, btw.
1970 - after Tyrannosaurus Rex but before the full-blown glam of T.Rex. The picture was originally in colour & was used as the album cover for the first album after the name change - [T.Rex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T._Rex_(album))

Comment: @Thanks, it is good to have more info about the origins of the picture, I didn't even think of the album cover.

Comment: I was just thinking I'd seen that exact picture somewhere before - a quick google gave me my "D'oh!" moment ;-) Very much the fashion of the time, though, for 'headshots' to be in black & white. They even got called after the company that printed them in the UK - they were simply known as 'WalkerPrints', like Hoover or Sellotape... the brand becomes the object.